# jQuery plugin only works on the last apperance of the selector

Tags: jquery

I'm doing a jquery plugin that moves the background of a div (based on another plugin). I don't understand why if I've only 1 on element using $(".video").moveBackground(); works well.
If I've 2 elements or more, only works the last one.

The code: http://jsfiddle.net/7PfEN/ . It doesn't works on jsfiddle but works fine (well, only the last) in local.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your problem is that the plugin uses a `sys` object for storing the animation timer, and the `sys` object is global for all of the elements you pass in via a single call to `.moveBackground()`.

So while this won't work...

```
$('.video').moveBackground();
```

I believe this would...

```
$('.video').each(function(){
  $(this).moveBackground();
});
```

Comment: Yes! This works! Thank you. By the way, what do you think about the performance? What is better? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

First, your jsFiddle is trying to `$(".image").moveBackground()` instead of `$(".video")`

But the real problem is that each call to init() is overwriting your **global** `sys.elem` value.  In greatly abbreviated form, here's an approach that might work for you:

```
function init(elem) {
  ...
  $(elem).hover( function() {
    ...
  });
}
...
return this.each(function () { init(this); });
```

You'll need to pass `elem` on down through the various functions, using it wherever you currently have `sys.elem`.